# Beginner leanback tutorials showing how to display and update browsefragment data

Tags: java, json, android-tv, leanback

I am trying to learn about developing android TV apps and looking at sample code on github and on some tutorial links. I have grasped some basics around android TV development.

My problem is non of the tutorials properly explain how the browse fragment is populated with data from an online json source and how it is updated.

Can anyone please direct me to a link or source that can be used as a decent tutorial for a beginner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any tutorials specifically for LeanBack, but you can probably find plenty of general android tutorials on how to use `Retrofit` to fetch json formatted data from a public API.

As for populating your `BrowseFragment`, something like this should do it:

```java
//Create a rows adapter for your fragment
ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);

//Create a row and populate it
ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(someItemPresenter);
listRowAdapter.setItems(someItems, someDiffCallback);
ListRow row = new ListRow(listRowAdapter);

//Add row
mRowsAdapter.add(row);
```

`someItems` should be a `List` of your fetched items. `someItemPresenter` should be a class that extends `Presenter` and handles items of the type contained in the someItems list. `someDiffCallback` should be a `DiffCallback`.